# visual studio code mac how to open a new window everytime drag a folder onto dock?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For visual Studio Code is there a way to open a new window every time I drag a folder onto the mac doc or drag a folder into the Editor window?

Comment: can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we replace the running instance when you drop something into the editor window and I think that is natural gesture when you drop into an instance.

As for dropping onto the dock, our version 0.3.0 contains a fix to support the behavior to open a new window!